# What does the determinant of the metric tensor tell you or show you?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I don't know what the determinant of the metric tensor tells you about that space. Also, is it possible to use the metric tensor to find the area of a curved surface or the volume?

Comment: You might want to ask the second question as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

A general change in coordinate system changes both $\int d^n x$ and $g:=\det g_{\mu\nu}$ in an $n$-dimensional spacetime, but preserves the integration measure $\int d^n x\sqrt{|g|}$. This can be used to define a volume under some conditions. For example, if a spacetime's spatial sections are compact we can define a finite "volume" $\int d^n x\sqrt{|g|}g^{00}$.